# Unable to parse xml file in python. getting parse error " ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 45, column 91 "

Tags: python, xml, lxml

XML file is generic and used in Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis

URL - https://github.com/davidsbatista/Aspect-Based-Sentiment-Analysis/tree/master/datasets/ABSA-SemEval2014

Code that I'm trying -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("Restaurants_Train.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

Error I'm getting

ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 45, column 91

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Restaurants_Train.xml is well-formed.

Comment: @mzjn - you are not getting any error ? can you share your python or library version?

It was working for me earlier, not anymore.

Comment: I have tested with both Python 2.7 and 3.6. There is no error.

Comment: Did you use the same code. Can you share the code ?

Comment: I used the code in the question.